# Laravel eloquent give wrong result

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have this code:

```
public function inbox()
{
    $id = Auth::user()->id;
    $bids = Bid::where('user_id',$id)
               ->where('status','0')
               ->orWhere('status','4')
               ->latest()->get();
               dd($bids);
    return view('rooms.inbox', compact('bids'));

}
```

and this is my database:
[image]

But when I run it I get this result:

[image]

my Auth user id is 8 but I get wrong results? Why?

ALso when i try ;
 `$bids = Auth::user()->bids()->get();` then I get right results///

What is problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are getting this unexpected error because of orWhere,you can do like this way

```
$bids = Bid::where('user_id',$id)
                       ->where(function ($query) {
                         $query->where('status','0')
                         ->orWhere('status','4');
                       })
                       ->latest()->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Advanced Where Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#advanced-where-clauses)

Your Query should like,

```
$bids = Bid::where('user_id',$id)
            ->where(function ($query) {
                $query->where('status', '0')
                    ->orWhere('status', '4');
            })->latest()->get();
```